# How should I go about finding a guild in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What strategies do you use to find the right guild for you in World of Warcraft?
Forums? Trade chat?
Should I be willing to realm transfer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be willing to transfer but I don't think it's good to blindly transfer.

There are many ways to look for a guild and your process has to change based on what you want out of a guild. Here are some methods from least involved to most involved.

1) trade chat: lots of guild advertise there. Pick one and try it.. if you don't like them try another.

2) PUG: Jump in random groups. If you like some one ask them about their guild. You can learn about tons of guilds that way.

3) apply: Lots of the top raiding guilds have an application process. These guilds are more serious about the content they play and PUG random people less so you might not meet them while trying to find random groups.

Important things to consider when looking for a guild are times of the day you are free and if that is when your new guild plans on runing guild events like raids and pvp. Some guilds focus more on results and less on the social side of the game. Knowing what you want out of a guild can go a long way to finding a good guild.

Comment: Mmo-champion is also a great source in the recruitment  http://www.mmo-champion.com/forums/244-Guild-Recruitment Has EU and US also has French, German and English also US Oceanic and lots of guilds advertise there including most top guilds

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the guild you want to find. If you're looking for a serious raider guild, there's pugs, trade chat, recruitment ads on popular forums, etc.

However, if you value intelligent chat over `we kild LK lol`, look for people who write complete and grammatically correct sentences, wherever you may find them. Also, girls: a guild with lots of girls has a much better probability of sane chat and members, simply because they'd leave if they were harassed by their own guildies.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to join a lot of groups and find people that you like playing with, then ask them for an invite to their guild. If you enjoy playing with someone and they take you under their wing for a guild invite you'll already have a leg up by knowing someone.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very good tool on [WoW Progress](http://www.wowprogress.com/):

Go to `Recruitment` tab and just fill everything to fit your needs. I found a suitable guild literally in an hour or something.

Only downside with this tool is that not every guild keep their info up to date all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find a good guild is to get to know people in real life who play WoW and find out what guilds they are in. I found my favorite guild since release through people at work.

As far as server transfers, I would only do so if you knew people beforehand who can vouch for the quality of the guild. Preferably people outside the game. Transfers are just too expensive to waste on a guild that might be a poor fit.

Mainly however, you have to decide what you really want out of a guild. If you are just looking for people to chat with while leveling, then your best bet might just be to join random guilds until you find a good fit, or run dungeons with random people and find some that you enjoy playing with.

If you are finding yourself more concerned with things like raiding it gets a little trickier. You will want to find a fairly organized guild, which pretty much rules out just about every guild that doesn't have some form of application process. If they advertise in trade and accept you on the spot, don't expect to be running many successful 25-mans in the near future. One easy first place to check is the server forums for whichever server you are focusing on. Find posts from guilds looking for members that have a solid guild site for you to peruse. Check out the application process for any red flags such as incapable or unreasonable raiding schedules.

In the end, a lot of it is just choosing one and seeing how things go. My best piece of advice after joining a guild is keep an eye on the leadership. While the non-officers of the guild will have a big impact on your experience of the guild, the officers will signal the overall direction the guild is heading.

Comment: If someone runs up and shoves a guild invite in your face, it's probably not a guild you'll enjoy being in...

Answer (score 1):

WoWProgress has always been my first stop for groups, guilds, etc. The recruitment tab is probably the best place to begin, but there are lots of places to poke around within WoWProgress. This article digs into some of the things you can do there: https://www.whatswithtech.com/wowprogress-best-wow-rankings-powerhouse/

Answer (score -1):

Shameless plug, but I built a tool to help with this exact thing. You can search for WoW guilds and join them pretty easily. Browsing around will give you a good idea of who is recruiting and what the guild specializes in. Check it out here:

[BattleStandards (http://battlestandards.com)](http://battlestandards.com)

Other than that, I think the most important thing is playing with someone from the guild and determining if you get along well. If you do, just ask them about their guild. You usually get a pretty honest answer.